# Spawning multiple instances of a class at different x position pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a Pong clone in pygame, but I'm having trouble spawning the paddles. My paddle class looks like this:

```
class Paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite, x_pos):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20,70))
        self.image.fill(colors["WHITE"])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x_pos
        self.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT/2
        self.y_speed = 0
```

And I try to spawn two of them at opposite sides of the screen with

```
player1 = Paddle(SCREEN_WIDTH - self.image.get_width() - 10) # Adjust for paddle width and border
player2 = Paddle(10)
```

But I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pypong.py", line 19, in <module>
    class Paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite, x_pos):
NameError: name 'x_pos' is not defined
```

I tried replacing `self.rect.x = x_pos` with `self.rect.x_pos = self.x_pos` but I still get the same error. I thought I was getting the hang of OOP but this threw me for a loop. Can anybody help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your class inherits from x_pos, it does not take x_pos as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the class that you've defined has some issues, and I think it's worth going over some of the basics first and then having a look at your class second. I've split the answer up into those two sections, so you can skip ahead if you must.

---

A python class can "see" the variables that are passed to it or defined within it. We do that passing and defining in the `__init__` method:

```py
class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, x_pos):
        ...
```

Note that the class itself doesn't take any arguments (it doesn't even have brackets!). Instead we pass all of the arguments that we want to use in our class to the `__init__` method! A class *can* be defined with brackets, but that's only when its a class that's based on another class, which is called a derived class:

```py
class pygame.sprite.Sprite:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...

class Paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
```

Next, we've seen that we can pass variables to classes via their `__init__` methods, but how do we store them in the class as *attributes* and use them in the class *methods* (functions)? We do that by prepending class attributes with `self.` like so:

```py
class Paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x_pos):
        ...
        self.x_position = x_pos
```

Now we can use that attribute in other methods in the class, not just in the `__init__` method:

```py
class Paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x_pos):
        ...
        self.x_position = x_pos

    def x_add_1(self):
        self.x_position += 1
```

The stuff inside the `x_add_1()` method knows about the `x_position` attribute because we passed `self` to the method, which is where the `x_position` attribute is stored (because we defined it as `self.x_position`).

So now we have a class, with an attribute (`self.x_position`) and a method (`x_add_1`), let's use it by creating an *instance* of the class:

```py
class Paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x_pos):
        ...
        self.x_position = x_pos

    def x_add_1(self):
        self.x_position += 1

player_1 = Paddle(5)
print(player1.x_position)
> 5
player1.x_add_1()
print(player1.x_position)
> 6
```

Now you can see how we made an instance of the `Paddle` class, and passed it the `x_pos` value of 5. We then accessed the `x_position` attribute of our `player_1` instance, and used the `x_add_1` method too.

---

Now let's see where you've run into some trouble:

```py
class Paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite, x_pos):
    def __init__(self):
    ...
```

First of all, you've made `Paddle` a derived class of `pygame.sprite.Sprite`. This seems reasonable. But you've also passed it `x_pos`, which *should* be passed to the `__init__` method, which you haven't passed anything! This is why you get your error that the `x_pos` isn't defined, because the `__init__` method has been told to use it but hasn't been passed it.

But once we've fixed that we're still in trouble:

```py
class Paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x_pos):
        ...
        self.image.fill(colors["WHITE"])
        self.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT/2
```

Your class hasn't been told about a dictionary called `colors`, nor an integer called `SCREEN_HEIGHT`. To be able to use those it would have to be passed them when the class is being instantiated.

```py
class Paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x_pos, colors, SCREEN_HEIGHT):
        ...
        self.image.fill(colors["WHITE"])
        self.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT/2
```

You don't have to store those new variables as class attributes if you don't think that you'll use them outside of the `__init__` method, but you could. For example you may want to make the paddle red when the ball hits it, in which case you will need to do make an attribute to store the `colors` dictionary:

```py
class Paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x_pos, colors, SCREEN_HEIGHT):
        self.colors = colors
        ...
        self.image.fill(self.colors["WHITE"])
        self.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT/2

    def paddle_hit(self):
        ...
        self.image.fill(self.colors["RED"])
        ...
```

That's probably all that you need to know to be able to fix your class. I haven't given you anything that you can copy and paste I'm afraid, but I've highlighted all of the problems that I can see (I *think*) and described how to fix them!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! This did the trick, and now I understand inheritance better ;)